# BG Image preloader in JQuery

Tags: jquery, image, preloader, preload, image-preloader

I have an array of images

```
var photos = ["images/bg01.jpg", "images/bg02.jpg", "images/bg03.jpg"];
```

I am cycling through this array and making them the background of a div based on a interval

```
$("#bgimg" + activeContainer).css({
        "background-image" : "url(" + photos[i] + ")",
        "display" : "block",
        "z-index" : currentZindex
    });
```

EDIT: I need to preload all three images before I do my setInterval function.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a variable to the number of images that have to be loaded. Decrement the counter each time an image finishes loading, and when the counter reaches zero, start showing the images.

```
function photoLoaded() {
    if(!--numPhotosLeft) {
        // start showing images
    }
}

var photos = ["images/bg01.jpg", "images/bg02.jpg", "images/bg03.jpg"];
var numPhotosLeft = photos.length;

for(var i = 0; i < photos.length; ++i) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = photoLoaded;
    img.src = photos[i];
}
```

Comment: so simple...didn't even think about that.

Answer (score 1):

```
(function($) {
    var photos = ["images/bg01.jpg", "images/bg02.jpg", "images/bg03.jpg"];

    var i = 0;
    function preloadImage() {

        var image = new Image();

        image.onload = function() {
            $("#bgimg" + activeContainer).css({
                "background-image" : "url(" + photos[i] + ")",
                "display" : "block",
                "z-index" : currentZindex
            });

            i++;
            preloadImage();
        };

        image.src = photos[i];


    };

}(jQuery);
```

This will...

1. load your image
2. set it to background of your container
3. repeat with next image

Comment: Sorry, edited orignal post. Your code is great, but I have an interval changing the CSS so I need to preload all images before running my setInterval function.  THANKS for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
var imgCount = images.length;
var counter = 0;
$.each(images, function(i, n) {
   // load each image
   $("<img />").attr("src", n)
               .load(function() {
                  counter++;
                  if(imgCount == counter) {
                     // all images have loaded
                     // call setInterval
                  }

              });
});
```